# How to store map selection?

Tags: qgis, area, select

I am working on a report that include different maps of the exact same area, with different items on it. My problem is that I need to select a portion of the US West Coast from a shapefile of the whole United States. I'm doing it manually, but of course each time I repeat the process, the selection is slightly different.

Is there a way to select specific areas and store such selection in order to be able to replicate it from scratch with no effort?

Comment: Check [QGIS atlas creation](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/automating_map_creation.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't have a separate .shp file with boundaries.. I have a .shp file of the United States, and I need to manually select a specific area

Comment: Funny story as I started a plugin to do that a while ago but never got it to core level https://github.com/NathanW2/selection-sets And I missed the QGIS 3 feature freeze doh!